# Update query using dynamic data in zend?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am using zend, I have the following code like

```
class Admin_Model_DbTable_Inv extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'test';
    public function updateproductstock($qty,$pid)
    {
        $data = array(
            'stock' => 'stock - 2'
        );
        $this->_db->update($this->_name, $data, product = '.$pid.');
    } 
}
```

Here,I want to subtract my qty from stock.For example 2 will be qty. `qty` will be dynamic data .How can i use zend update here. kindly help.

Updated my post

Comment: $db-> refers to a database object (class).  Please can you post the class to which this piece of code refers?  Or at least the 'update' function

Comment: @luc, I agree the question is a little vagueness but with the reference to zend framework you can imagine that it refers to http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html and his update method.

Comment: @LukeCoulton This is Zend Framework, `update` is a method from Zend_Db.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the zend-framework tag.  I use the zend studio purely for programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 class Admin_Model_DbTable_Inventory extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
 {
     protected $_name = 'test';

     public function updateproductstock($qty,$pid)
     {
         $data = array(
             'stock' => new Zend_Db_Expr('stock - '.$qty);
         );
         $this->_db->update($this->_name, $data, product = '.$pid.');
     }
 }
```

Comment: Actually i want to subtract the stock value from qty in test table

Comment: Well then read the current stock value from the database, and use the code of my answer (I am going to edit it)

Comment: Yes , But suppose  if i have 10 products in my cart, I  will loop this  updateproductstock function .Then it will take some time to execute. This will not be effective then.

Comment: sorry for my mistake.I gave it for only example...will update the post now

Comment: Ok I finally got what you wanted to do. See my edit, maybe a Zend_Db_Expr will do, it will prevent the string from being escaped by Zend_Db (so it will be a valid SQL expression).

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Admin_Model_DbTable_Inv extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
 {
     protected $_name = 'test';

     public function updateproductstock($qty)
     {           
         $r = $this->fetchRow($this->select()->where('product  = ?', 1));
         $r->stock -= $qty;
         $r->save();
         $data = array(
             'stock' => 'stock - '.(string) $qty;
         );
         $this->_db->update($this->_name, $data, "product = '1'");
     }
 }
```

ps: All the variables should be prefix with $

Comment: $values = array('stock' => 'stock - 2');
  $oDb->update('test', $values, 'product_id = 34');  this updates 0 value in current_stock, and when i run this     $values = array('stock' => '41 -'.(string)2);
  $oDb->update('test', $values, 'product_id = 34'); it updates 41 as stock and it does not subtract the stock. SO this query is not working.

Comment: @Dinesh you are getting 0 probably because your column is INT, so if you fill it with a string, it will be converted to an integer (which will give here 0). See my answer, maybe it will work.

Comment: @Matthieu you're right, I don't understand as long as no variable could be recognized...